# How can I plot st error bars with seaborn relplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar, relplot

I am studying different variables. I want to plot the results with the stadnard error.

I use the filter function because depending on what I want to analyse, I am interested in just plotting mineral, or just plotting one material...etc. I mention this because it is important for the error bars. With seaborn it is not possible to plot the error bars (I used the raw data and I introduced in the seaborn function cd='', but it does not work. Therefore, I have calculated the mean and st error in excel and I plot that directly. The table is the result of the average and the st error that I use in the script.
If I add ci in the seaborn, does not do anything. Therefore I want to add it externally in a second line. But I have tried with ax.errorbar(), I cant either plot the st error.

```
import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
Results = pd.read_excel('results.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1',usecols="A:J")
df=pd.DataFrame(Results)

RR_filtered=Results[(Results['Mineral ']=='IC60') | (Results['Mineral ']=='MinFree')]
R_filtered=RR_filtered[(Results['Material']=='A')]

palette = ["#fdae61","#abd9e9"]
sns.set_palette(palette)
ax1=sns.relplot( data=R_filtered,x="Impeller speed (rpm)", y="Result",col="Media size ",hue="Mineral content (g/g fibre)",
palette=palette,size="Media size ",sizes=(50, 200))

R2_filtered=RR_filtered[(Results['Material']=='B')]
ax2=sns.relplot( data=R2_filtered,x="Impeller speed (rpm)", y="Result",col="Media size ",hue="Mineral content (g/g fibre)",
palette=palette,size="Media size ",sizes=(50, 200))
plt.show()
```

[image]

[data as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ddZq.png)

```
Media size  Material    Impeller speed (rpm)    Energy input (kWh/t)    Mineral     Mineral content (g/g fibre) Result  ster
1.7 A   400 3000    IC60    4   3.42980002276166    0.21806853183829
1.7 A   650 3000    IC60    4   5.6349292302978 0.63877270588513
1.7 A   900 3000    IC60    4   6.1386616444364 0.150420705145224
1.7 A   1150    3000    IC60    4   5.02677117937851    1.05459146256349
1.7 A   1400    3000    IC60    4   3.0654271029038 0.917937247698497
3   A   400 3000    IC60    4   8.06973541574516    2.07869756201064
3   A   650 3000    IC60    4   4.69110601906018    1.21725878149246
3   A   900 3000    IC60    4   10.2119514553564    1.80680816945106
3   A   1150    3000    IC60    4   7.3271067522139 0.438931805677489
3   A   1400    3000    IC60    4   4.86901883487513    2.04826541508181
1.7 A   400 3000    MinFree 0   1.30614274245145    0.341512517371074
1.7 A   650 3000    MinFree 0   0.80632268273782    0.311762840996982
1.7 A   900 3000    MinFree 0   1.35958635068886    0.360649049944933
1.7 A   1150    3000    MinFree 0   1.38784671261469    0.00524838126778526
1.7 A   1400    3000    MinFree 0   1.12365621425779    0.561737044169193
3   A   400 3000    MinFree 0   4.61104587078813    0.147526557483362
3   A   650 3000    MinFree 0   4.40934493149759    0.985706944001226
3   A   900 3000    MinFree 0   5.06333415444978    0.00165055503033251
3   A   1150    3000    MinFree 0   3.85940865344646    0.731238210429852
3   A   1400    3000    MinFree 0   3.75572328102963    0.275897272330075
3   A   400 3000    GIC 4   6.05239906571977    0.0646300937591957
3   A   650 3000    GIC 4   7.9023202316634 0.458062146361444
3   A   900 3000    GIC 4   6.97774277141699    0.171777036954104
3   A   1150    3000    GIC 4   11.0705742735252    1.3960974547215
3   A   1400    3000    GIC 4   9.37948091546579    0.0650589433632627
1.7 A   869 3000    IC60    4   2.39416757908564    0.394947207603093
3   A   859 3000    IC60    4   10.2373958352881    1.55162686552938
1.7 A   885 3000    BHX 4   87.7569689333017    10.2502550323564
3   A   918 3000    BHX 4   104.135074642339    4.77467275433362
1.7 B   400 3000    MinFree 0   1.87573877068556    0.34648345153664
1.7 B   650 3000    MinFree 0   1.99555403904079    0.482200923313764
1.7 B   900 3000    MinFree 0   2.54989484285768    0.398071770532481
1.7 B   1150    3000    MinFree 0   3.67636872311402    0.662270521850053
1.7 B   1400    3000    MinFree 0   3.5664978541551 0.164453275639932
3   B   400 3000    MinFree 0   2.62948341485392    0.0209463845730038
3   B   650 3000    MinFree 0   3.0066638279753 0.305024483713006
3   B   900 3000    MinFree 0   2.79255446831386    0.472851866083359
3   B   1150    3000    MinFree 0   5.64970870330824    0.251859240942665
3   B   1400    3000    MinFree 0   7.40595580787647    0.629256778750272
1.7 B   400 3000    IC60    4   0.38040036521839    0.231869270120922
1.7 B   650 3000    IC60    4   0.515922221163329   0.434661621954815
1.7 B   900 3000    IC60    4   3.06358032815653    0.959408177590503
1.7 B   1150    3000    IC60    4   4.04800689693192    0.255594912271896
1.7 B   1400    3000    IC60    4   3.69967975589305    0.469944383688801
3   B   400 3000    IC60    4   1.35706340378197    0.134829945730943
3   B   650 3000    IC60    4   1.91317966458018    1.77106692180411
3   B   900 3000    IC60    4   0.874227487043329   0.493348110823194
3   B   1150    3000    IC60    4   2.71732337235447    0.0703901684702626
3   B   1400    3000    IC60    4   4.96743231003956    0.45853815499614
3   B   400 3000    GIC 4   0.325743752029247   0.325743752029247
3   B   650 3000    GIC 4   3.12776074994155    0.452049425276085
3   B   900 3000    GIC 4   3.25564762321322    0.319567445434468
3   B   1150    3000    GIC 4   5.99730462724499    1.03439035936441
3   B   1400    3000    GIC 4   7.51312624370307    0.38399627585515
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.2`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`, `seaborn 0.12.1`**

### Sample DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Media size': [1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.7, 3.0, 1.7, 3.0, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
        'Material': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'Impeller speed (rpm)': [400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 869, 859, 885, 918, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400, 400, 650, 900, 1150, 1400],
        'Energy input (kWh/t)': [3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000, 3000],
        'Mineral': ['IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'BHX', 'BHX', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'MinFree', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'IC60', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC', 'GIC'],
        'Mineral content (g/g fibre)': [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], 'Result': [3.42980002276166, 5.6349292302978, 6.1386616444364, 5.02677117937851, 3.0654271029038, 8.06973541574516, 4.69110601906018, 10.2119514553564, 7.3271067522139, 4.86901883487513, 1.30614274245145, 0.80632268273782, 1.35958635068886, 1.38784671261469, 1.12365621425779, 4.61104587078813, 4.40934493149759, 5.06333415444978, 3.85940865344646, 3.75572328102963, 6.05239906571977, 7.9023202316634, 6.97774277141699, 11.0705742735252, 9.37948091546579, 2.39416757908564, 10.2373958352881, 87.7569689333017, 104.135074642339, 1.87573877068556, 1.99555403904079, 2.54989484285768, 3.67636872311402, 3.5664978541551, 2.62948341485392, 3.0066638279753, 2.79255446831386, 5.64970870330824, 7.40595580787647, 0.38040036521839, 0.515922221163329, 3.06358032815653, 4.04800689693192, 3.69967975589305, 1.35706340378197, 1.91317966458018, 0.874227487043329, 2.71732337235447, 4.96743231003956, 0.325743752029247, 3.12776074994155, 3.25564762321322, 5.99730462724499, 7.51312624370307],
        'ster': [0.21806853183829, 0.63877270588513, 0.150420705145224, 1.05459146256349, 0.917937247698497, 2.07869756201064, 1.21725878149246, 1.80680816945106, 0.438931805677489, 2.04826541508181, 0.341512517371074, 0.311762840996982, 0.360649049944933, 0.0052483812677852, 0.561737044169193, 0.147526557483362, 0.985706944001226, 0.0016505550303325, 0.731238210429852, 0.275897272330075, 0.0646300937591957, 0.458062146361444, 0.171777036954104, 1.3960974547215, 0.0650589433632627, 0.394947207603093, 1.55162686552938, 10.2502550323564, 4.77467275433362, 0.34648345153664, 0.482200923313764, 0.398071770532481, 0.662270521850053, 0.164453275639932, 0.0209463845730038, 0.305024483713006, 0.472851866083359, 0.251859240942665, 0.629256778750272, 0.231869270120922, 0.434661621954815, 0.959408177590503, 0.255594912271896, 0.469944383688801, 0.134829945730943, 1.77106692180411, 0.493348110823194, 0.0703901684702626, 0.45853815499614, 0.325743752029247, 0.452049425276085, 0.319567445434468, 1.03439035936441, 0.38399627585515]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

### Map `plt.errorbar` onto `sns.relplot`

```
# filter the dataframe by Mineral
filtered = df[(df['Mineral']=='IC60') | (df['Mineral']=='MinFree')]

# plot the filtered dataframe
g = sns.relplot(data=filtered, x="Impeller speed (rpm)", y="Result", col="Media size", row='Material', hue="Mineral content (g/g fibre)", size="Media size", sizes=(50, 200))

# add the errorbars
g.map(plt.errorbar, "Impeller speed (rpm)", "Result", "ster", marker="none", color='r', ls='none')
```

[image]

### Specify `color` for each group of errorbars

- `plt.errorbar` only accepts one value for color. In order to match the colors to a palette, the specific data for each facet needs to be selected, and the proper color for that group passed to the `color` parameter.

  - errorbars that are smaller than the circle can't be seen.

```py
# create a palette dictionary for the unique values in the hue column
palette = dict(zip(filtered['Mineral content (g/g fibre)'].unique(), ["#fdae61", "#abd9e9"]))

# plot the filtered dataframe
g = sns.relplot(data=filtered, x="Impeller speed (rpm)", y="Result", col="Media size", row='Material', hue="Mineral content (g/g fibre)", size="Media size", sizes=(50, 200), palette=palette)

# iterate through each facet of the facetgrid
for (material, media), ax in g.axes_dict.items():
    # select the data for the facet
    data = filtered[filtered['Material'].eq(material) & filtered['Media size'].eq(media)]
    # select the data for each hue group
    for group, selected in data.groupby('Mineral content (g/g fibre)'):
        # plot the errorbar with the correct color for each group 
        ax.errorbar(data=selected, x="Impeller speed (rpm)", y="Result", yerr="ster", marker="none", color=palette[group], ls='none')
```

[image]